# Why can't I use the word “data” as a variable name in Lazarus

Tags: lazarus

I was trying to read from a wav soundfile. The data in soundfile is distributed in chunks. Every chunk started with an array[0..3] of char. I was unable to find the “data” chunk. First I thought it was in the seek function (the soFromBeginning soBeginning problem) or a type mismatch. After long search a found that the problem disappeared when I changed the variable name.

Here is the procedure as much as possible simplified to the problem.

```
    procedure readwavformattest1(filenamein: string);
    var
      f: TFileStream;
      data: array[0..3] of char;
      aantalread: longint;
    begin
      try
        f := TFilestream.Create(filenamein, fmopenread);
        aantalread := f.Read(data, sizeof(data));
        if aantalread < sizeof(data) then
          Exit;
      finally
        f.Free;
      end;
    end;


    procedure readwavformattest2(filenamein: string);
    var
      f: TFileStream;
      datal: array[0..3] of char;
      aantalread: longint;
    begin
      try
        f := TFilestream.Create(filenamein, fmopenread);
        aantalread := f.Read(datal, sizeof(datal));
        if aantalread < sizeof(datal) then
          Exit;
      finally
        f.Free;
      end;
    end;
```

Procedure 2 is working and gives for wav files for data “RIFF”, procedure 1 gives for data “nil”. Both give for aantalread the good result of 4
The only difference in the procedures is the var name “data” versus “datal”
I don't understand what is going wrong. Data isn't a reserved word, and if it was, the compiler should give an error. If data is an already declared variable, the local variable should be used. If I omit the declaration of data, data is an unknown variable for the compiler.(All debug checking is on)
Somehow I can't use the word “data” as variable name.

Answer (score 1):

It should simply work, and I've *not* seen bugs in something this basic in a long time, I assume it must be something in what you are not showing (like code messing up the stack).

Best is to reduce the problem to its absolute minimum (like a 100 lines console program) and submit it to the  [FPC bugtracker](http://bugs.freepascal.org)

If the problem goes away while reducing, that is a strong indication that an out of bounds memory access is happening somewhere.

Comment: Submitted to FPC bugtracker as issue 26347. It seems to be a problem in the debugger. Hoovering the mouse above the variable gives the wrong answer while actually in the variable was the right value stored.